# Dynamic SQL performance - parameters or string concat?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

In terms of performance, when dealing with dynamic SQL and and ADO.NET connection, is it preferred to pass parameters or using a plain text SQL statement string when there is input?

Is there a difference performance wise between

1. Using parameters

   ```
   public void InsertData(DateTime dateFor, string message)
   {
       using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
       {
           connection.Open();

           var sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Data] (DateFor, Message) VALUES(@DateFor, @Message);";
           connection.Execute(sql, new { DateFor = dateFor, Message = message });
       }
   }
   ```

and

2. Using a plain text SQL statement

   ```
   public void InsertData(DateTime dateFor, string message)
   {
       using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
       {
           connection.Open();

           var sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Data] (DateFor, Message) VALUES('{0}', '{1}');", dateFor.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), message);
           connection.Execute(sql);
       }
   }
   ```

Should I be inclined to use one method over another?

(I am using Dapper for this example, if anyone is wondering about the data binding syntax)

Comment: (obligatory for option #2: https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @jdphenix let's say in a scenario where parameters are controlled and not provided by the user

Comment: Queries with parameters can be prepared by the db. On execution only parameters are transferred to a precompiled statement.

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks, how can they be prepared if the SQL code in not stored on the DBMS?

Comment: read the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SirRufo I red it and did not learn much...am I missing something?

Comment: Well on that page is also an example in C# - What else do you need?

Comment: There are many other factors that would influence the performance of an INSERT statement much more. e.g. Choice of primary key, clustered index etc. A prepared, parameterized, statement sent via ado.net will give SQL Server a much better chance to create a good plan for the query and therefore be much more likely to perform better than an ad-hoc statement.

Comment: @fallenidol thanks for the first legit answer